# Need to remove extra "\" from a directory path in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, window

I am very new to Batch scripts.

Currently I am writing one batch script and in that I am getting a path from one file like below:

```
C\\:\\\Program Files\\\Product\\\Install
```

Now I want it like below:

```
C:\Program Files\Product\Install
```

Basically I want to remove those extra \, so how can I achieve this in a easy way?

Comment: You should fix the problem that **causes** the extra "\" characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "_path=C:\\Program Files\\Product\\Install"
set "_path=%_path:\\=\%"
echo %_path%
```

Comment: This solution looks good, but still not perfect. Please note the "\" in "C\:", that also needs to be removed. It should look like "C:"

Comment: So it could be further set like      set "_path=%_path:\:=:%"  to get the desired result. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
set "badPath=C:\\Program Files\\Product\\Install"
for %%a in ("%badPath%.") do set "goodPath=%%~fa"
echo %goodPath%
```

This uses a `for` loop to handle the conversion making use of the replaceable parameter modifiers (see `for /?` for the full list).

Note: The ending dot used in the `for` loop is included to ensure removal of the ending backslashes in case they are present. If you don't need it, you can remove the dot.

Comment: Not working correctly, its prepends current directory path also in goodpath, so not useful for me.

Comment: @amuser, having absolute paths as shown in the question this can not happen. You will only get the current path added if you are handling relative paths.